# Grails - Sending "multipart/form-data" request to API

Tags: api, grails, kanban

I'm trying to use the Kanbanize API to add attachments to a ticket but their documentation is really bad and I don't know how to translate the specification into working Grails code. The documentation can be found [here](https://kanbanize.com/api/#add_attachment). Here's what I've tried:

```
def addAttachment(ticket, attName, attType, attBytes) {

    // println attName // outputs " capital.pdf "
    // println attType // outputs " application/pdf "
    // println attBytes // outputs " [37, 80, 68, ...] ", assume it's a valid byte array

    try {
        def http = new HTTPBuilder("https://examplesubdomain.kanbanize.com/index.php/api/kanbanize/add_attachment")
        http.request( Method.POST, groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON ) { req ->
            headers = [
                'apikey':'secretApiKey',
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=AnyStringNotFoundInTheBody'
            ]
            body = [
                params: [
                    boardid:123,
                    taskid:123,
                ],
                'Content-Disposition': ''+attBytes+'; name="'+attName+'"; filename="'+attName+'"',
                'Content-Type': attType,
            ]
            response.success = { resp, json ->
                ret = json
            }
        }
        println ret // This statement is never reached
    } catch(all) {
        all.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

In the above code, I println `attName`, `attType` and `attBytes`, to show what those look like, I receive those values from an upload form. If the above is insufficient to answer the question, let me know and I'll upload the implementation of the upload form too.
Also, I censored the following values in the above code:

- `examplesubdomain` in the URL of the HTTPBuilder.
- `secretApiKey` in the headers
- `boardid`. This for simplicity.
- `taskid`. This for simplicity.

The error that the above code produces:

```
Error |
groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
Error |
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.defaultFailureHandler(HTTPBuilder.java:652)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1265)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:949)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
Error |
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:508)
Error |
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:441)
Error |
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:390)
Error |
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$request.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.service.KanbanizeService$$EQyblqIi.addAttachments(KanbanizeService.groovy:84)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.service.KanbanizeService$$DQyblqIi.__execute(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.service.KanbanizeService.__execute(KanbanizeService.groovy)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.service.KanbanizeService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$e7c466db.invoke(<generated>)
Error |
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
Error |
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
Error |
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
Error |
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
Error |
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
Error |
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.service.KanbanizeService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$89b01036$$E0.addAttachments(<generated>)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.service.KanbanizeService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$89b01036$$D0.__execute(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.service.KanbanizeService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$89b01036.__execute(<generated>)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.service.KanbanizeService$addAttachments.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.service.KanbanizeService$addAttachments.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.control.admin.AdminKanbanizeController$_logTicket_closure1$$EQybhHWS.doCall(AdminKanbanizeController.groovy:69)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2.invoke(ReloadedTypeInvoker.java:122)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1288)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.control.admin.AdminKanbanizeController$_logTicket_closure1.call(AdminKanbanizeController.groovy)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.control.admin.AdminKanbanizeController$_logTicket_closure1.call(AdminKanbanizeController.groovy)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1326)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1298)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$148.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error |
    at unipoint.club.control.admin.AdminKanbanizeController$$EQybhHWS.logTicket(AdminKanbanizeController.groovy:66)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2.invoke(ReloadedTypeInvoker.java:122)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1288)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:69)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:348)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:231)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:197)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:118)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:72)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:328)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
Error |
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
Error |
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.ehcache.EhcachePageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(EhcachePageFragmentCachingFilter.java)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:318)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:283)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:274)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:203)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:206)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:152)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
Error |
    at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter.doFilter(DevModeSanityFilter.groovy:45)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:66)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
Error |
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
Error |
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
Error |
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
Error |
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
Error |
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
Error |
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I see that the tag `api` is not allowed, but there's no `kanbanize-api` or `api-request` tags so that did seem the most appropriate.

If I forgot anything and need to include any further details please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is Milen from Kanbanize R&D team. I'm not familiar with Grails so I won't be able to provide working code but I can point some mistakes in the code you have given.

1. The boundary string is missing between the parts of the body. Each part should begin with `--AnyStringNotFoundInTheBody` and the body should end with `--AnyStringNotFoundInTheBody--` 
   (You can replace `AnyStringNotFoundInTheBody` with whatever you like on the condition that it's unique string in the body)
2. The params section is not JSON-encoded
3. The value of `Content-Disposition` should be `form-data` and the actual binary data of the image should be placed at the end.

It would help to print the text representation of the request that you send and compare it with the sample one that we have provided in the documentation.
Also, when the API rejects a request there is usually an error that points the concrete reason. So, printing the response would help, too.

Let us know if you need further help and/or contact us directly at support  kanbanize.com

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I posted the question here, instead of asking you guys directly, because I figured my question might've been generally answerable and that I only needed help with API requests in general, but I'll carry on the conversation through your support channels.